# UPS Shipping Label displays "SAMPLE"

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, ups

We have configured a new account with UPS with Magento 1.7 CE

We got all the settings, access codes and etc entered:

[image: UPS plugin settings]

Negotiated rates are showing up no problem, but when trying to create a label we get "SAMPLE" on the label.

This is confusing because the configuration is clearly set to LIVE rates.

I have been on email tag with UPS API support and have not gotten a clear message. They say to replace ONE of the urls in the settings to https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/XAV - which after trying doesnt pull up any UPS rates at all.

It doesn't also change anything about the "SAMPLE" problem - even after re-creating the label and deleting the old one it still shows "SAMPLE" on them.

Do I need to do some kind of label certification like Fedex? I dont see this anywhere in the manuals for UPS api and support has not answered that question either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer - apparently UPS plugin hasnt been updated by Magento (100,000 stores) in a while.

I had to replace a couple of lines in \app\code\core\Mage\Usa\Model\Shipping\Carrier\Ups.php

FROM:

```
 /**
 * Default urls for shipment
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_defaultUrls = array(
    'ShipConfirm' => 'https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipConfirm',
    'ShipAccept'  => 'https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipAccept',
);
```

TO:

```
/**
 * Default urls for shipment
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_defaultUrls = array(
    'ShipConfirm' => 'https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipConfirm',
    'ShipAccept'  => 'https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipAccept',
);
```

Of course I put this into \app\code\local\Mage\Usa\Model\Shipping\Carrier\Ups.php

PS: checked 1.9.4.0 code and this seems to be patched in that version. Not sure if I missed a patch for 1.7.0.2 or it's not patched at all.